# To use Selenium web driver or selenium RC

Tags: selenium

Is it a good idea to start new test framework using Selenium web driver instead of Selenium RC? 
With Selenium web driver not all Selenium methods are implemented. So would it be a good idea to use Selenium RC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriver. Simply because WebDriver is actively developed and maintained, more stable and functional, has better API.

RC is no longer developed and maintaned and WebDriver is the future of Selenium.

Comment: I wanted to capture Network traffic using Selenium. 

I am able to use RC's .start("captureNetworkTraffic=true") ans .stop(), to do it. 

I don't see any other way using webdriver. 

So should I use WebDriver????

Answer (score 2):

Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each browser’s native support for automation. How these direct calls are made, and the features they support depends on the browser you are using. Information on each ‘browser driver’.

For those familiar with Selenium-RC, this is quite different from what you are used to. Selenium-RC worked the same way for each supported browser. It ‘injected’ javascript functions into the browser when the browser was loaded and then used its javascript to drive the AUT within the browser. WebDriver does not use this technique. Again, it drives the browser directly using the browser’s built in support for automation.

So better use webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need to do.  <strike>However, I found selenium RC to be a better choice because I could write a test program that was connected to ant to run unit tests regularly with a continuous integration/build system.</strike>

I did have to write a few wrapper methods to simulate things that used to be one liners in RC.  The biggest issue is that converting tests from Selenium IDE to Web Driver often skips a lot of commands as they are not implemented.

Managing windows for popups is the most annoying part.  You have to find the new window handle, switch to it, do your work, call close() and then switch back to the first window.  That last part is critical or the rest of the suite will fail due to the browser shutting down from confusion.

Ant now kicks off a browser directly (via junit @beforeclass) rather than running it on selenium grid using the Jenkins selenium plugin.

Comment: And why do you think that we can't do the same with WebDriver based tests? I have them running with Hudson

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Web Driver. Comparative to Selenium RC web driver test execution is much more faster. In Selenium RC you need to start the stand-alone-server separately but in web driver since it has native calls you don't need to get your self trouble about it.

When it comes to handling browser pop-up's, alerts, parent child windows web driver is the best solution. Capturing screenshots in any browser is not an issue with web driver. Drag & Drop also web driver supports mobile test automation. If you need to execute your test silent mode(without browser opening) only web driver will able to handle it.

There is a cool reference test automation framework built with Web driver, NUnit & Log4Net. It's known as "SeShell" http://seshell.org you can download the setup and can have some experience the power of web driver